# Time spent writing algorithm for Map tile cutting and rendering

Tags: maps, tiles

I know this a very vague question but I really need to know this.

Can anyone help me finding a kinda of matrix that shows how much time spent by different companies writing their map tile cutters/renderers like Google,Bing,Yahoo, OpenStreetMap, Maptiler, Mapnik (at the heart of TileMill) and Geoserver tile rendering system.

Since I need to make a rough estimate that if I start writing the entire tile cutting and rendering mechanism in house then how much time,resources and money do I need.

Will appreciate all the answers.

Comment: Well, it all depends. You can typically simple use tools to generate the tiles without writing a single line of code: for example, using TileMill to create the map, export to Mapnik format and serve it using TileStache...

Comment: Regardless, that's a very vague question and depends, for example, on the complexity of the info you want to present and the source of the data. Also, something that's not negligible at all, is the time (and storage) it takes to generate the tiles. For example, just at zoom level 13 you'll need 4^13 tiles

Comment: appreciate your comments